# member function as callback function to g_signal_connect

Tags: c++, gtk

I have created a simple class for creating gtk main window.

I want to know what is correct way to pass class member function as an argument to G_CALLBACK function?

Why

> g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(&MainWindow:
>   nButtonClicked), NULL);

is bad?

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

class MainWindow {
public:
    MainWindow();
    ~MainWindow();
    void onButtonClicked(GtkWidget* button, gpointer* data);
    void showWindow();

private:
    GtkWidget* window;
    GtkWidget* button;
};
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect(window, "delete_event", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("click here");
    g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(&MainWindow: nButtonClicked), NULL);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), button);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}

void MainWindow::onButtonClicked(GtkWidget* button, gpointer* data)
{
    g_printerr("button clicked\n");
}

void MainWindow::ShowWindow() {
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    MainWindow mainWindow;
    mainWindow.showWindow();

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to pass a static function and the this-pointer:

```
class Window 
{
    public:
    virtual void on_button_clicked(GtkWidget* button);

    void connect_button_clicked(GtkWidget* button) {
        g_signal_connect(
            button, 
            "clicked", 
            G_CALLBACK(button_clicked_callback), this);
    }

    private:
    static void button_clicked_callback(GtkWidget* button, gpointer* data) {
        reinterpret_cast<Window*>(data)->on_button_clicked(button);
    }
};
```

Passing a pointer to a member function will not work (incompatible types and no reference to an object). If the c-callback mechanism does not support custom data (the this pointer here) things will get ugly.

Comment: thanks for your reply! But in the code I also wanted to know what is problem? There will be one extra call...

Answer (score 0):

Although static methods happen to work with some compilers (most notably gcc), someone [told me](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2011-March/msg00085.html) this is not always the case.

The proper way is to declare the callback (or at least a wrapper function) outside the class. Better yet, use proper [C++ bindings](http://www.gtkmm.org/) for GTK+. Better yet, use C.